# configure sub bullets in rich text component

Tags: html, css, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, aem

I have bulleted list plugin avaiable in the rich text editor.Is there any **subbulleted list** plug in available for the rich text component as my requirement is to have **sub bullets under bullets**.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the richtext component does not provide such functionality. 
But it is possible to create ordered and unordered lists and to intend or outend the single list items.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomas, i will try to implement the same